# ng-change detect if ng-model is null or invalid in select box and select first valid option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have hundreds of cases like this (so the fix would have to be global and not tied to just this particular example)

There is a lot of select boxes like this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem">
 <option ng-repeat="item in items | filter:attributes" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

The `selectedItem` variable is null (and it will always initialize as null, which can't be changed in the controller in this particular situation).

What I'm trying to figure out is a way to globally watch all `<select>` elements in a view, see if the `ng-model` variable for that `<select>` box is `null` and if it is `null` set it to the first valid option in that select box, anytime the scope changes it will need to check if the ng-model is `null` and auto-select the first valid option.

Answer (score 2):

The key thing to realise with this is that you can define more than one Angular directive with the same name, and all of them will be run for matching elements.

This is very powerful, as it enables you to extend functionality of built-in directives, or third party ones, etc.

Using this, I was able to create a `select` directive that would select the first valid option in the list whenever the model value is null.

One thing it doesn't do, however, is cope if you remove the selected item from the list (it goes back to being blank). But hopefully it is enough to get you started.

```js
var app = angular.module('stackoverflow', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedItem = null;
  $scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4].map(function(id) {
    return {
      id: id,
      visible: true,
      text: 'Item ' + id
    };
  });
});

app.directive('select', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs, ngModel) {
      // don't do anything for selects without ng-model attribute
      if (!ngModel) return;
      // also allow specifying a special "no-default" attribute to opt out of this behaviour
      if ($attrs.hasOwnProperty('noDefault')) return;
      // watch the model value for null
      var deregWatch = $scope.$watch(function() {
        return ngModel.$modelValue;
      }, function(modelValue) {
        if (modelValue === null) {
          // delay to allow the expressions to be interpolated correctly
          setTimeout(function() {
            // find the first option with valid text
            var $options = $elem.find('option'),
              $firstValidOption, optionText;
            for (var i = 0, len = $options.length; i < len; i++) {
              optionText = $options.eq(i).text();
              if (optionText !== '' && !optionText.match(/^(\?|{)/)) {
                $firstValidOption = $options.eq(i);
                break;
              }
            }
            if ($firstValidOption) {
              $firstValidOption.prop('selected', true);
              ngModel.$setViewValue($firstValidOption.attr('value'));
              // trigger a digest so Angular sees the change
              $scope.$evalAsync();
            }
          }, 0);
        }
      });

      // clean up in destroy method to prevent any memory leaks
      var deregDestroy = $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        deregWatch();
        deregDestroy();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="stackoverflow">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedItem">
      <option ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{visible:true} track by item.id" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.text}}</option>
    </select>
    <p>Visible items:</p>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.visible">{{item.text}}
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```